# System of equations$ \frac{x-a}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}} + \frac{x-c}{\sqrt{(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2}} = 0$

Tags: systems-of-equations

While solving a bigger problem, I stumbeled upon a system of parametric equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\dfrac{x-a}{\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)^2+\left(y-b\right)^2}} + \dfrac{x-c}{\sqrt{\left(x-c\right)^2+\left(y-d\right)^2}} = 0\\
\dfrac{y-b}{\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)^2+\left(y-b\right)^2}} + \dfrac{y-d}{\sqrt{\left(x-c\right)^2+\left(y-d\right)^2}} = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
I need to solve it. I don't actually need all of the solutions to this system, one is enough.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Infinite solutions include trivial solutions where $x-a=c-x$ and $y-b=d-y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $d_1=\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)^2+\left(y-b\right)^2}$ and $d_2=\sqrt{\left(x-c\right)^2+\left(y-d\right)^2}$ are the distances from
the point $(x,y)$ to the points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, respectively. Rewrite the given system as

$$\frac{x-a}{c-x}= \frac{y-b}{d-y}= \frac{d_1}{d_2}$$

So, geometrically,  $(x,y)$ represent all the points on the line connecting $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be : find the extremum of function
$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{(a-x)^2+(b-y)^2}+\sqrt{(c-x)^2+(d-y)^2}$$ If you do not have any constraint, it could be any point along the line explained by @Quanto in his/her answer.